virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory lukechilds/dockerpi
I am trying to compile a ~10MB C++ file on a docker container lukechilds/dockerpi which is a raspberry-pi docker image. I have given 8 GB for docker engine.
pi@raspberrypi:~$ g++ lenet5-forward-train.cpp
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
The C++ file compiles in around 15-20 minutes on my laptop with 8GB RAM and i5-3rd generation.

So why don't you break the file into smaller pieces and compile them separately? Separate compilation is a feature of C++ after all.

Can you give some examples of this.

I take it you are not a C++ programmer. This is not the place for a tutorial in C++, but a typical C++ program consists of many functions which can be split into groups with each group being compiled separately. Then the resulting object files are then linked together at the end. This will use far less memory. This is how C++ development is normally done. Having a single 10MB C++ file is extremely unusual. For more focussed help I think you should give a little background to where this file came from and what you are trying to achieve.

Going by the filename, the bulk of that 10MB file is an encoding of a binary weights file? There are alternative ways of embedding that file into your final binary while keeping your C++ code limited to actual code. See dup for an approach that will not choke your compiler.
